# I broke an LCD tv screen, could it be dangerous?

Tags: lcd, tv, smart-tv

I accidentally broke my TV(Strange circumstances led to a cracked screen. I've read that it can be dangerous and deadly because there could be something called MBBA inside. It's an LG smart TV (I don't know the model or anything, it's my parents...) but it cracked and there's supposed to be liquid crystal inside. Is it dangerous? Nothing is leaking out yet, but should I get the TV out of the house? It's pretty late, and I'm tired(I've been up all night cleaning bc relatives are coming over soon) and I want to go to bed. Can I leave it in the house overnight? Please answer quickly, I want to go to sleep.

Comment: Looking at the wiki page for [MBBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MBBA) there is an [NFPA 704](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFPA_704) icon showing blue:0 red:1 yellow:0. The blue shows it is not harmful to health, the yellow that it does not react with water or instantaneously converts into some other harmful chemical, and the red shows it will only combust when significant heat is applied. You are probably in no immediate danger, just don't go licking anything that oozes out of the screen and wash your hands if you do touch anything and you should be fine.

Comment: I read about a guy who cut his finger on a piece of the broken glass from the display and got some of the liquid in the wound.  A week later, his fingernail turned into a mini LCD display the showed everything he was thinking.  He had to wear gloves so people didn't read his mind.  It must be true because it was on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The only real danger from a broken LCD screen is if the glass is falling out, then you would want to deal with the broken glass issue.  There are no liquids or such at risk, you can easily leave it in the house.  At this point I'd probably unplug it as it no longer will need power.

Bear in mind though that it is an electronic device and if it was still under power and if you were to bend it more to increase the breakage and if you were to have your hand on just the right spot and if you were just unlucky enough, you might get a little zap out of it.  Note the many 'if's' of the statement.

Have a good night.

mc